# Why flip the Metal output image if it has same coordinate system as iOS?

Tags: metal

I'm reading [this page](https://metalbyexample.com/textures-and-samplers/) on the Metal by Example site, and it says:

> In Metal, the origin of the pixel coordinate system of a texture
> coincides with its top left corner. This is the same as the coordinate
> system in UIKit... The coordinate system of the texture coordinates
> must agree with the coordinate system of the image data. Since it is
> most natural to work in an image editor where the origin is in the top
> left, the saved image will often be upside-down from the perspective
> of the Metal texture coordinate system.

The example is stating that both Metal and an example image editor have the origin in the same place -- upper left -- so then, why, would it suggest it will be upside down? If the origin in one was lower left and the other upper left, I'd understand the need to flip it, but not in this example. What am I missing? The two coordinate systems are the same, but the image is still upside-down?

Comment: But the image you want to display has a different coordinate system, right?

Comment: @FrankSchlegel why would it have a different coordinate system, if an editor has the same coordinate system as the Metal texture (as noted in the quoted example), which also has the same coordinate system as an iOS UIImage, all with origins in the upper left.

Answer (score 0):

From the sample that you were provided above:

> Unfortunately, UIKit does not provide a way to access the underlying bits of a UIImage. Instead, we have to draw the image into a Core Graphics bitmap context that has the same format as our desired texture.

**Metal loads textures from CGImage data (Core Graphics Framework), not from UIImage.**

Each of the drawing frameworks of iOS establishes a default coordinate system based on the current graphics context. In iOS, there are two main types of coordinate systems:

- An upper-left-origin coordinate system (ULO), in which the origin of
  drawing operations is at the upper-left corner of the drawing area,
  with positive values extending downward and to the right. The default
  coordinate system used by the UIKit and Core Animation frameworks is
  ULO-based.
- A lower-left-origin coordinate system (LLO), in which the origin of
  drawing operations is at the lower-left corner of the drawing area,
  with positive values extending upward and to the right. The default
  coordinate system used by Core Graphics framework is LLO-based.